# Registre du mot 'auparavant'

Tags: usage, registre

- Auparavant, ce journal n’était disponible qu’en ligne.
- Sport auparavant réservé à une élite, le golf s’est démocratisé.

J'ai entendu des personnes dire que le mot *auparavant* est considéré comme soutenu et il faut éviter l'utiliser en français parlé relâché. Cette affirmation est-elle vraie ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J'ignore s'il **faut** vraiment éviter de le dire dans un contexte relâché, mais ça sonne en effet soutenu et ce n'est pas du tout habituel.
Quelques suggestions pour le remplacer :

- avant,
- à une époque (moins courant et suggère que c'était il y a longtemps),
- par le passé (idem, encore moins courant).

Ce qui donne pour le premier exemple :

- Avant, ce journal n'était disponible qu'en ligne.

La deuxième phrase est plus complexe car sa structure même n'est pas courante à l'oral, on pourrait dire :

- Le golf s'est démocratisé alors qu'à une époque, c'était réservé à une élite.